# Inner sill corrosion implications in Rover 45 2003

Tags: corrosion

At my last MOT I had advisories that the Nearside inner sill had slight corrosion and the Offside front inner sill slight corrosion. Is it safe to drive and if not is it worth getting it repaired. The reason I'm reluctant to get rid is I have brakes for life, complete new exhaust, Cambelt and water pump replacement, new clutch and brand new Uniroyal Rain Sport tyres. The body work has no rust at all and it drives perfectly.

Comment: A photo of the corroded spots could be helpful

Answer (score 5):

At the time of the MOT, if it was unsafe to drive, it would have failed the test.

An advisory like this one is letting you know that something is starting to look like it could eventually fail a future test.  In your case, they are letting you know that rust has started to form on an important part of the vehicle, so you have the opportunity to lengthen the life of your car by getting it treated rather than leaving it to get worse.

If this is the first time this rust has been advised about, it may be a simple job of wire brushing the rust down and applying some underseal, which could save a lot of money in the future if you do nothing about it.

Answer (score 4):

MOT advisories are just things that they think you should know, if it was unsafe your car wouldn't have passed its MOT. Sill corrosion is a sign that the frame is weakening, and will eventually become unsafe, but that could take a number of years.

As for whether it's worth fixing or not is generally a matter of opinion, however looking at auto-trader I can tell you that your car is probably worth about £1500, and sill repair is likely going to come close to that value, if not exceed it, and you wouldn't add any value to the car. There's probably rust in lots of places as well, and it's a rabbit hole that is not worth going down unless the car has sentimental value.

What you need to know to decide is how much it will cost to fix. There's nothing wrong with getting a quote from a body shop and then making a decision based on that. Or you could take the approach to keep driving it until it rusts past safety limits and get a newer car.